# Class not found when unmarshalling: com.facebook.login.LoginClient$Request

Tags: android, facebook-login, classnotfoundexception

I am trying to integrate Facebook loginbutton in my loginPage.I am getting following error.

```
01-27 01:33:12.051 2440-2451/? E/Parcel: Class not found when unmarshalling: com.facebook.login.LoginClient$Request
                                     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.facebook.login.LoginClient$Request
```

xml code is like :

```
 <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
            android:id="@+id/fb_signin"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
```

activity code is like :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    fbcallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    fbSigninButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fb_signin);
    fbSigninButton.registerCallback(fbcallbackManager, fbCallback);
}
  private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> fbCallback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        Log.d(TAG, "loginresult = " + loginResult);
        String name = loginResult.getAccessToken().getApplicationId();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString(Constants.CONST_USER_NAME, name);
        launchHomewithBundle(b);


    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException error) {

    }
};
```

Please help me in fixing this issue .

note : I already tried other
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1721610004736672/ noHistory issue . but its not working.I have already googled for the solution but it is not working.

Comment: Sorry fella, i hv stopped following it .@kevskree.